# glBufferData: sending data with vector of vector

Tags: c++, opengl

I usually have a situation where I just send data to opengl buffers using a vector like this:

```
std::vector<float>cSplinePointsData;
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myTreeInventory[currentInventoryItem]->cSplinePointsData.size() * sizeof(float), &myTreeInventory[currentInventoryItem]->cSplinePointsData[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);
```

However, what if I need to use a vector of vector? As much as I tried nothing gets drawn on screen. My code is as follows:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> cSplinePointsData;
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myTreeInventory[currentInventoryItem]->cSplinePointsData.at(ID).size() * sizeof(float), &myTreeInventory[currentInventoryItem]->cSplinePointsData.at(ID)[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I basically modified the code that worked with a single std::vector so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work with the second approach.

Comment: Think about how the floats are laid out in memory.  The elements of a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` are *not* contiguous in memory.